# java function to return either False or object

Tags: java, python, recursion, types

I'm working on a function that will be recursively called in a backtracking scenario. Either the function worked and will return the working list, or it fails and return `false`. In python, I can write this:

```
def myfunc(input):
    # logic and logic
    if fails:
        return False
    return alist
```

In java, a function can't return a List or False. I think I can skirt around the problem with (`?` just for argument sake, I know what I'm returning):

```
public List<?> myfunc(someType input){
    // logic and logic
    return res
    // empty or special result instead of False.
}
```

But is there a more elegant way to do this? perhaps `try catch`? I'm quite fresh in java and would want to know the standard in this case. Thanks.

Comment: You can always return null, or use Optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options:

### Using [java.util.Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

```
public Optional<List> myfunc(someType input){
    // logic and logic
    if (fail) return Optional.empty();
    else return Optional.of(res);
}
```

### Return `null`

```
public List myfunc(someType input){
    // logic and logic
    if (fail) return null;
    else return res;
}
```

### Throw exception

```
public List myfunc(someType input){
    // logic and logic
    if (fail) throw new RuntimeException("What an interesting case!");
    else return res;
}
```

PS. I would recommend Optional or exception.

Comment: Recommended (or not) by who?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Perhaps the usage of `Optional` here is a bit superfluous, as Optional may just indicate a lack of return value. However, looking at OP's original question, it seems more in line with what they wanted.

Comment: It also forces the callee to explicitly check for null-values (or null-cases), as Optional explicitly indicates this

Answer (score 1):

You can return a null list on failure.

```
 public static ArrayList<String> GetList()
 {
     return null;
 }
```